# How to set the password filed inline (UI issue)?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am building a signup form and encountered a UI issue.

I want two things to be done:

- `Confirm Password` label should be in the one same line i.e. inline
- `eye` icon should be inside the password input.

#### I have this currently

[image]

#### I want this

- The first point is already explained.
- For the second point I want below password field with `@` (replaced with eyeicon) at the end of the field.

[image]

#### code

This is just **UI issue** , so you can skip to the backend code. I have used inbuilt bootstrap -classes.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SignupPage = (props) => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [showConfmPassword, setShowConfmPassword] = useState(false);

  const goToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/login");
  };

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confmpassword: "",
    role: "guest",
    forgetQues: "",
    forgetAns: "",
  });

  const onChange = (e, key) => {
    setCredentials((prevCredentials) => ({
      ...prevCredentials,
      [key]: e.target.value,
    }));
    //console.log(credentials);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: credentials.name,
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
        role: credentials.role,
        forgetQues: credentials.forgetQues,
        forgetAns: credentials.forgetAns,
      }),
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    //console.log(json);

    if(json.success === true) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', json.authToken);
      navigate("/");
      props.showAlert("User Registered Successfully !","info");
    }
    else {
      props.showAlert("Invalid Credentials","danger");
    }

  };

  function togglePasswordVisibilty (){
    setShowPassword(!showPassword ? true:false)
  }

  function toggleConfmPasswordVisibilty (){
    setShowConfmPassword(!showConfmPassword ? true:false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-3">
        <div id="loginbody">
          <div className="mt-3">
            <h2 className="my-3 display-3">Create your account here </h2>
            <form className="login-form p-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  value={credentials.name}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "name")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>
              {/* --------------- */}
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                  Email{" "}
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={credentials.email}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "email")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
              <div className="pass-wrapper" style={{display:"flex",alignItems:"center"}}>
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  type={showPassword ? "text":"password"}
                  className="form-control mx-3"
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  minLength={5}
                  value={credentials.password}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "password")}
                  required
                />
                <i className={ showPassword ? "fas fa-eye-slash mx-2":"fas fa-eye mx-2"} title={ showPassword?"Hide Password":"Show Password"} onClick={togglePasswordVisibilty}></i>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
              <div className="pass-wrapper" style={{display:"flex",alignItems:"center"}}>
                <label htmlFor="confmpassword" className="form-label">
                  Confirm Password
                </label>
                <input
                  type={showConfmPassword ? "text":"password"}
                  className="form-control mx-3"
                  id="confmpassword"
                  name="confmpassword"
                  value={credentials.confmpassword}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "confmpassword")}
                  minLength={5}
                  required
                />
                <i className={ showConfmPassword ? "fas fa-eye-slash mx-2":"fas fa-eye mx-2"} title={ showConfmPassword?"Hide Confirmed Password":"Show Confirmed Password"} onClick={toggleConfmPasswordVisibilty}></i>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3 col-md">
                <label htmlFor="role" className="form-label">
                  <strong>Role</strong>
                </label>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline mx-4">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role1"
                    value="admin"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role1">
                    Admin
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role2"
                    value="client"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role2">
                    Client
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role3"
                    value="guest"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role3">
                    Guest
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3 row">
                <div className="form-floating col-6">
                  <select
                    className="form-select"
                    id="forgetQues"
                    name="forgetQues"
                    value={credentials.forgetQues}
                    aria-label="Floating label select example"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "forgetQues")}
                  >
                    <option>Open this select menu</option>
                    <option value="Favourite Sport">Favourite Sport</option>
                    <option value="Favourite Food">Favourite Food</option>
                    <option value="Favourite City To Visit">
                      Favourite City To Visit
                    </option>
                  </select>
                  <label htmlFor="forgetQues">Select Question</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                  <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="forgetAns"
                      name="forgetAns"
                      value={credentials.forgetAns}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "forgetAns")}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="forgetAns">Answer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-4 col-6 mx-auto">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success ">
                  SignUp
                </button>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text center my-3">
                  Already have an account ?
                </div>
                <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-3 col-6 mx-auto">
                  <button onClick={goToLogin} className="btn btn-success ">
                    Login Here!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question  :  Give enough width to 'label' so that it gets fit in the same line .

Answer to second question : Wrap the input and eye icon in a div -->
remove the border and outline of input tag , give width as 100% -->  Make the wrapper display:flex , align-items:center, border : 1px solid gray
Your code  for the confirm password issue should somewhat look like this

```
  `<div style={{border:1px solid "gray",
         display:flex,
         align-items:center;}}  >
       ​<input

             ​type={showConfmPassword ? "text":"password"}
             ​className="form-control mx-3"
             ​id="confmpassword"
             ​name="confmpassword"
             ​value={credentials.confmpassword}
             ​onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "confmpassword")}
             ​minLength={5}
             ​required
             style={{border:0,outline:none;width:100%;}}
           ​/>
           ​<i className={ showConfmPassword ?"fas fa-eye-slash mx-2"
                :"fas fa-eye mx-2"} title={ showConfmPassword?"Hide 
                Confirmed Password":"Show Confirmed Password"} onClick= 
               {toggleConfmPasswordVisibilty}>
           </i>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue and used the above answer approach, below is the correct code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SignupPage = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [showConfmPassword, setShowConfmPassword] = useState(false);

  const goToLogin = () => {
    navigate("/login");
  };

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confmpassword: "",
    role: "guest",
    forgetQues: "",
    forgetAns: "",
  });

  const onChange = (e, key) => {
    setCredentials((prevCredentials) => ({
      ...prevCredentials,
      [key]: e.target.value,
    }));
    //console.log(credentials);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: credentials.name,
        email: credentials.email,
        password: credentials.password,
        role: credentials.role,
        forgetQues: credentials.forgetQues,
        forgetAns: credentials.forgetAns,
      }),
    });

    const json = await response.json();
    //console.log(json);

    if (json.success === true) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", json.authToken);
      navigate("/");
      props.showAlert("User Registered Successfully !", "info");
    } else {
      props.showAlert("Invalid Credentials", "danger");
    }
  };

  function togglePasswordVisibilty() {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword ? true : false);
  }

  function toggleConfmPasswordVisibilty() {
    setShowConfmPassword(!showConfmPassword ? true : false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-3">
        <div id="loginbody">
          <div className="mt-3">
            <h2 className="my-3 display-3">Create your account here </h2>
            <form className="login-form p-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  value={credentials.name}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "name")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>
              {/* --------------- */}
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                  Email{" "}
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={credentials.email}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "email")}
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
                <div
                  className="pass-wrapper"
                  style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  <label
                    htmlFor="password"
                    className="form-label"
                    style={{ width: "200px" }}
                  >
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      border: "1px solid #ced4da",
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      width: "100%",
                    }}
                  >
                    <input
                      type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                      className="form-control mx-3"
                      id="password"
                      name="password"
                      minLength={5}
                      value={credentials.password}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "password")}
                      style={{ outline: "none", border: 0 }}
                      required
                    />
                    <i
                      className={
                        showPassword
                          ? "fas fa-eye-slash mx-2"
                          : "fas fa-eye mx-2"
                      }
                      title={showPassword ? "Hide Password" : "Show Password"}
                      onClick={togglePasswordVisibilty}
                    ></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3">
                <div
                  className="pass-wrapper"
                  style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  <label
                    htmlFor="confmpassword"
                    className="form-label"
                    style={{ width: "200px" }}
                  >
                    Confirm Password
                  </label>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      border: "1px solid #ced4da",
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      width: "100%",
                    }}
                  >
                    <input
                      type={showConfmPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                      className="form-control mx-3"
                      id="confmpassword"
                      name="confmpassword"
                      value={credentials.confmpassword}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "confmpassword")}
                      minLength={5}
                      required
                      style={{ border: 0, outline: "none" }}
                    />
                    <i
                      className={
                        showConfmPassword
                          ? "fas fa-eye-slash mx-2"
                          : "fas fa-eye mx-2"
                      }
                      title={
                        showConfmPassword
                          ? "Hide Confirmed Password"
                          : "Show Confirmed Password"
                      }
                      onClick={toggleConfmPasswordVisibilty}
                    ></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="mb-3 col-md">
                <label htmlFor="role" className="form-label">
                  <strong>Role</strong>
                </label>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline mx-4">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role1"
                    value="admin"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role1">
                    Admin
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role2"
                    value="client"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role2">
                    Client
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input
                    className="form-check-input"
                    type="radio"
                    name="roleOptions"
                    id="role3"
                    value="guest"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "role")}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="role3">
                    Guest
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3 row">
                <div className="form-floating col-6">
                  <select
                    className="form-select"
                    id="forgetQues"
                    name="forgetQues"
                    value={credentials.forgetQues}
                    aria-label="Floating label select example"
                    onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "forgetQues")}
                  >
                    <option>Open this select menu</option>
                    <option value="Favourite Sport">Favourite Sport</option>
                    <option value="Favourite Food">Favourite Food</option>
                    <option value="Favourite City To Visit">
                      Favourite City To Visit
                    </option>
                  </select>
                  <label htmlFor="forgetQues">Select Question</label>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                  <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="forgetAns"
                      name="forgetAns"
                      value={credentials.forgetAns}
                      onChange={(e) => onChange(e, "forgetAns")}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="forgetAns">Answer</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-4 col-6 mx-auto">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success ">
                  SignUp
                </button>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div className="mb-3 text-center">
                <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text center my-3">
                  Already have an account ?
                </div>
                <div className="d-grid gap-2 my-3 col-6 mx-auto">
                  <button onClick={goToLogin} className="btn btn-success ">
                    Login Here!
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```